# How to execute a php file in background from another php file

Tags: php, multithreading, php-5.6

I have two files, `file_a.php` and `file_b.php`. In file `file_a.php`, I'm trying to execute `file_b.php` as a "background process". I tried two ways I have found here on stackoverflow, but i can't make it work:

**file_a.php (exec solution)**

```
echo "Start ".time()."<br>";
exec("php -f /Path/to/file/file_b.php /dev/null &");
echo "End ".time()."<br>";
```

**file_a.php (curl solution)**

```
echo "Start ".time()."<br>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.1:8888/file/file_b.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "End ".time()."<br>";
```

**file_b.php (5 seconds delay and a sample mail send)**

```
set_time_limit(5);//setting five seconds delay
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {

    sleep(1);
}

// the message
$msg = "line of text";
// send email
mail("testmail@test.io","My subject",$msg)
```

I'm trying to call `file_a.php` and execute `file_b.php` without waiting 5 seconds in `file_a.php`, exactly as a background process.
There is a way to manage a similar behavior in PHP before PHP 7 for which i have seen some dedicated libraries?

Comment: Why do you need to run this background process? Can it wait an hour or does it have to be done now? Seems like you need a cron job

Comment: i want to free user who use file_a.php from waiting until the end of file_b.php execution (in real life application file_b.php will create an long execution time, something like 4 or 5 seconds, i need a very quick response for the file_a.php instead)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file **background.sh** with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php -f /Path/to/file/file_b.php &
```

and then call it using the first method

```
echo "Start ".time()."<br>";
exec("/bin/bash background.sh");
echo "End ".time()."<br>";
```

The shell will read the BASH script, run the PHP file in background and immediately return to your original script.

The more robust solution is to use some queue system, e.g. [PHP-Resque](https://github.com/mjphaynes/php-resque)